# Getting the full HTML Response with Google Search API

Tags: php, seo, google-search, google-search-api

i am trying to get the full html response of an http request with Google Search API.

`GET https://www.googleapis.com/customsearch/v1?key=MY_API_KEY&exactTerms=site:trovaweb24.com&cx=017576662512468239146:omuauf_lfve`

The result is a JSON PAGE that does not contain the html response.
How can i get the html code of a google search with their API?

The content of the page

Comment: Why would you expect a html response? Does the API documentation state that is possible? Normally an API is designed to just return data. You can then use it however you want, including displaying it in a html page if you wish. But you have the flexibility to use it in other ways too.

Comment: ADyson : because in their page there is written" Retrieve and display search results from Google Custom Search programmatically".

Comment: Well you got the results. They're just in JSON format, not HTML. If are you are quoting from https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/overview, the page is even titled "JSON API", and says "Custom Search JSON API can return results in JSON data format.". I think it's pretty clear. There is nothing at all there which mentions HTML - you seem to have simply imagined or assumed that, without reading the rest of the content. Unless you are quoting from a different page?? If so, please provide a link.

Comment: @Adyson i agree with you. I just want to get all the links of the results of a Google Search for a specific query. Is it possible?

Comment: Well, isn't that what the JSON results contain? As per https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/reference/rest/v1/Search#Result

Comment: @Adyson YES! Where is the url to call to get this json output?

Comment: It's all there in the documentation. Read the Introduction page: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/v1/introduction